# Aurelia style binding in option repeat.for

Tags: aurelia

This works in chrome but not in IE

```html
<option repeat.for="colour of typeColours" css="color: #333333; background-color:${colour};">
```

the only recommendation was to use css instead of style which I've done but cant find any other info on how to create an select drop down with different coloured rows that works cross browser.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: Its IE 11 Im pretty sure that will be the minimum version used..

Comment: Was it a color vs colour spelling thing?

Answer (score 0):

works in IE 11 and Edge for me:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pRZikbYw0q0DTahgGktQ?p=preview

```html
<template>
  <select>
    <option repeat.for="color of colors" css="color: white;background-color: ${color}">${color}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

```js
export class App {
  colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I've got at the moment. maybe I have an out of date version of Aurelia.. It is a couple of months old since I installed.